# I could be a fruit or an embarrassing faux pas

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> I could be a fruit or I could be an embarrassing faux pas
> I could be what you want with one that drops your jaw
> I could be more boring, just a descriptor of your days
> I could be many things, but I go by just one name

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are a

> DATE

I could be a fruit

> A date is a fruit

or I could be an embarrassing faux pas

> I think this is referencing something being 'dated' as in old-fashioned and out of the current trends. For example, an out-of-date gesture or mannerism. You also may embarrassingly date yourself, as in "I remember watching the first Super Bowl when I was ten."

I could be what you want with one that drops your jaw

> You may want to date someone who amazes you

I could be more boring, just a descriptor of your days

> Days are dates, yep pretty boring

I could be many things, but I go by just one name

> All these are the word DATE!